# Is there a metal that melts and solidifies quickly?

Tags: metal, melting-point

Is there any kind of metal that melts very quickly with very low heat or temperature, and at the same time, becomes hard very quickly?

Comment: Mercury is liquid at room temperature and gallium melts in your hand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMekQGnnQjI . But this just addresses melting points, I'm not sure what you mean by 'quickly' - the heat dispersion rate? Solder works good for this, if you don't mind the 300 degrees or so it takes to melt it.

Answer (score 5):

The melting points of some eutectic mixtures are tabulated in an article by French.<sup>1</sup> Some options for low-melting point metals/mixtures are:

- Gallium-indium eutectic, mp 15.7 °C ([Sigma-Aldrich catalogue](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/495425))
- Galinstan, mp –19 °C ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinstan))
- Various gallium-based Indalloy® alloys, mp between 7.6 and 29.78 °C ([corporate page](http://www.indium.com/thermal-interface-materials/other/liquid-metal/))
- A general search for "fusible alloys" brings up several sources with many choices:

  - [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusible_alloy)
  - [Rotometals sales page](https://www.rotometals.com/low-melt-fusible-alloys/)
  - [Belmont sales page](http://www.belmontmetals.com/product/eutectic-alloys/)
  - [Bolton Metal sales page](http://www.boltonmetalproducts.com/Home_Page.html)

---

*Reference*

1. French, S. J. Melting Points of Eutectics. *Ind. Eng. Chem.* **1936,** *28* (1), 111–113. [DOI: 10.1021/ie50313a026](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie50313a026).

Answer (score 4):

Some bismuth alloys have rather low melting points.

*Wood's metal* (50% bismuth, 25% lead, 12.5% cadmium and 12.5% tin) melts around 70 °C.

*Field's metal* (51% indium, 32.5% bismuth and 16.5% tin) melts around 62 °C.

An alloy of 44.7% bismuth, 22.6% lead, 19.1% indium, 8.3% tin and 5.3% cadmium melts around 47 °C.

Answer (score 2):

There is a game, which is a tradition in Germany around New Year, to predict good fortune for the upcoming year: [Molybdomancy (german - Bleigießen)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdomancy) While this is unscientific jibber jabber, there is actually some real physics involved.

Tin has a (very) low melting point ($\approx \pu{230 ^\circ C}$) which can easily be achieved with a candle. If you pour the molten tin into water, it will immediately become solid again. (This also works with lead $\approx \pu{330 ^\circ C}$, but that is very toxic.)